# nodejs async waterfall use function from external required javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I am fairly new to nodejs, and to keep my code brief, was hoping I could use functions from a .js file I include in my async waterfall list of functions.  I have tried to include one function, and am getting either a 'TypeError: callback is not a function' exception or 'Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of undefined'.  I have searched and searched and cannot find an answer, but hoping someone can give me the best way, as with callbacks and functions I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Am hoping my code will be like this:

```
var module1 = require('./lib/module1.js'),
   module2 = require('./lib/module2.js');

async.waterfall([
   module1.externalfunc1,
   module2.externalfunc2
], function (err, result) {
if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ');
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log('Completed streaming1');
    console.log(result);
}
```

My guess is I should put the waterfall functions inside another function, like function(){module1.externalfunc;},function(){module2...

Think I am just not understanding callbacks well enough, as I'm not sure if the external function will know what "callback" is since its outside of the code with waterfall.  But I have to believe this is possible.

Thanks for any help.

meant to say, i have externalfunc1 created with a function defined, which i export, so in the file have:

```
function externalfunc1(param1, callback){...} 
module.exports = externalfunc1;
```

Comment: If you meant to say something different than is in your question, then just use the "edit" link to edit your question to fix it.

Comment: I suspect that you are not exporting the functions correctly, can you share the contents of the `module1.js` file?

Comment: To use the external functions directly, they have to have the exact right calling signature (exact same arguments) that `async.waterfall()` expects.  If they don't, they you have to wrap them in another function that does.

Comment: Thanks, @asosnovsky and jfriend00, i added my edit above, its exactly like that, a function with 2 parameters, param1 the func uses, and the callback.  Export only the function name.  do i need `module.exports = externalfunc1(param1, callback)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that you are exporting the function `externalfunc1` as your entire module. I.e.

```
var module1 = require('./lib/module1.js')
module1  === externalfunc1
```

Either change the export to :

```
module.exports = { externalfunc1 }
```

or import as :

```
var externalfunc1 = require('./lib/module1.js')
```

Comment: Thanks @asosnovsky that fixed it, clearly i wasn't understanding exactly what i was exporting